# Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle

Tags: python, ssl, pip, certifi

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /pathtodownloadedfile/cacert.pem

This error occur when I want to install a package from Python 3.10. My operating system is macOS and my IDE is Pycharm. I did try those method on the internet for example edit the _CACERT_PATH in the site-packages/pip/certifi/core.py but it definitely not work. Also I had restart my IDE and went to the ApllicationSupport file but not found the pip file.